# popToRootViewController: viewControllers still in memory?

Tags: ios, memory, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift

I have a question about the iOS popToRootViewController UINavigationController method. Here a very simple diagram of what's happening in my architecture (storyboard):

[image]

When I go through this cycle several times, I hear the audio player object is playing more then once.  **That's how I found out the mainviewcontroller of the previous cycles is still existing in memory**...  How can I avoid this?  What is the effect of the performance of the app?  Does this create a memory leak?

Comment: It is very unlikely. Do you explicitly stop the audio before pop back?

Comment: Yes I did, so iOS will unload those objects you think?  Then I will make an example to check this for real.

Comment: This almost always occurs because you have a strong reference to that controller somewhere, so it is not being released.